# Logistic regression multiclass classification with Python API

Tags: python, classification, logistic-regression

currently the Python API does not yet support multi class classification within Spark, but will in the future as it is described on the Spark page [1](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#classification).

Is there any release date or any chance to run it with Python that implements multi class  with Logistic regression? I know it does with Scala, but I would like to run it with Python. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

scikit-learn's [LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) offers a `multi_class` parameter. From the docs:

> Multiclass option can be either ‘ovr’ or ‘multinomial’. If the option
>   chosen is ‘ovr’, then a binary problem is fit for each label. Else the
>   loss minimised is the multinomial loss fit across the entire
>   probability distribution. Works only for the ‘lbfgs’ solver.

Hence, `multi_class='ovr'` seems to be the right choice for you.

For more information: [see this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/821347/MultiClass-Logistic-Classifier-in-Python)

---

Added:

As per the pyspark documentation, you can still do multi class regression using their API. Using the class `pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS`, you get the optional parameter `numClasses` for multi-class classification.

Comment: In scikit-learn's and scala api also has LogisticRegression with multi-class, as per my understanding question is *does this will be added in PySpark API for python developer?*

Comment: I have tried your suggestion since I am also stuck in such problem, can you please check question on [data science stackexchange](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13673/logistic-regression-as-multiclass-classification-using-pyspark-and-issues), I am hopeful that you will resolved my issue.

Comment: I have posted my problem and full source code at [github repo](https://github.com/krishnaiitd/LogisticRegression), please check and do let me know If I am missing something?